# How to paste excel table in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How to paste excel table in ckeditor ?

In the [demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo) I'm available to paste formatted table but in my case the table is pasted as plain text. I believe it is something to do with the config of ckeditor but couldn't find it.
Should I install some plugins ?

I've tried this in `config.js`

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    config.pasteFromWordPromptCleanup = false;
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = false;
    config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false;
    config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = false;
    config.removeFormatAttributes = false;
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours I found a solution. it seems that all html was removed, not only tables.

I added this to the config.js :

```
    CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false; // default so content won't be manipulated on load
    CKEDITOR.config.basicEntities = true;
    CKEDITOR.config.entities = true;
    CKEDITOR.config.entities_latin = false;
    CKEDITOR.config.entities_greek = false;
    CKEDITOR.config.entities_processNumerical = false;
    CKEDITOR.config.fillEmptyBlocks = function (element) {
            return true; // DON'T DO ANYTHING!!!!!
    };
```

[Source](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Editor-changing-html)

Answer (score 0):

Following settings to the config file has worked for me

```
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = false;
config.pasteFromWordPromptCleanup = false;
config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = false;
config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;

CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.removeFormatAttributes = false;
CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false; 
CKEDITOR.config.basicEntities = true;
CKEDITOR.config.entities = true;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_latin = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_greek = false;
CKEDITOR.config.entities_processNumerical = false;
CKEDITOR.config.fillEmptyBlocks = function (element) {
    return true; 
}
```