# use a MS Word and MS Excel's cell from the ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm use ckeditor.

I do not speak English because Koreans..Please understand !

I like to use a word and excel's cell from the ckeditor

Please see below

1) test Excel and Word..

http://i58.tinypic.com/f9ebs8.jpg

2) result (Copy the cell to ckeditor)

http://i57.tinypic.com/28v6ah2.jpg

Why is the status of excel?
cell's Attribute is not copy..

please Answer. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please see this https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/4665 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762705/how-to-paste-excel-table-in-ckeditor